# Confused on how to perform "next" function using Soundcloud api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have my player go to next song but I cant seem to get my code to work. So far play and pause work perfectly but the next function is not responsive.

```
SC.get("/tracks/316493713").then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
})
SC.get("/tracks/323674116").then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
})

//create an object to hold track id and SC stream
function SoundCloud(){
  this.trackId = [316493713,323674116]
  this.song = SC.stream('/tracks/' + this.trackId[index])
}

var jukebox = new SoundCloud();
//play
SoundCloud.prototype.play = function() {
  this.song.then(function(player) {
    player.play();
  })
}
//pause
SoundCloud.prototype.pause = function(){
  this.song.then(function(player){
    player.pause();
  })
}

//next functionality not working.
SoundCloud.prototype.next = function(){
  this.song.then(function(player){
    if(index === this.song.length-1){
      index =0;
    } else {
       index++;
    }
    this.song.currentTime = 0;
    this.song.play();  
  })
}
```

Comment: In `SoundCloud.prototype.next` you're using the variable `index` which is not in scope, hasn't been declared, assigned to ect prior to that if statement so fixing that is probably a good starting point.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal is there any way to do this without changing my original sound cloud constructor? Im kind of stuck.

Comment: Yeah I don't think your constructor needs to be changed. I think the problem is generally with your use of `index` - `if(index === this.song.length-1)` at that point what is index? Where is it declared? You do use it in the constructor as well though; `this.trackId[index]` - that variable is never in scope in this file. Fix that first.